# Launch HTML code in browser (that is generated by BeautifulSoup) straight from Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have used BeautifulSoup for Python 3.3 to successfully pull desired info from a web page. I have also used BeautifulSoup to generate new HTML code to display this info. Currently, my Python program prints out the HTML code, which I then have to copy, paste, and save as an HTML file, then from there, I can test it in a browser.

So my question is this, is there a way in Python to launch the HTML code generated by BeautifulSoup in a web browser so that I don't have to go through the copy and paste method I use now?

Comment: More options here: [Can beautiful soup output be sent to browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706214/can-beautiful-soup-output-be-sent-to-browser/25706243#25706243)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Using [`webbrowser.open`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open):

```
import os
import webbrowser

html = '<html> ...  generated html string ...</html>'
path = os.path.abspath('temp.html')
url = 'file://' + path

with open(path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Alternative using [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) (to make the file eventually deleted by OS):

```
import tempfile
import webbrowser

html = '<html> ...  generated html string ...</html>'

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False, suffix='.html') as f:
    url = 'file://' + f.name
    f.write(html)
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the simple solution I was looking for for now.

Comment: [NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tempfile.html) with delete = False may be preferrable here, as it will (likely) get deleted eventually by the OS

Comment: @Jay, Thank you for the comment. Updated the answer to include an alternative using NamedTemporaryFile.

Comment: I needed to use
```with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False,suffix=".html") as f: ```
to get it to render the html properly in the browser. Otherwise I just saw the raw html string in my browser.

Comment: @marvin, Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/) to turn your code into a local web application:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def scrape_and_reformat():
    # call your scraping code here
    return '<html><body> ... generated html string ... </body></html>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Run the script, and point your browser at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`.

Comment: or just SimpleHTTPServer?

Comment: @reptilicus, FYI, no SimpleHTTPServer in Python 3.x, but [`http.server`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html).

Answer (score 1):

(this grew enough I figured I should split it off as a separate answer:)

As @reptilicus points out, you can use the built-in [http.server](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server) module as follows:

1. Create a web file directory and save your .html file in it.
2. Open a command-line window and do

   ```
   cd /my/web/directory
   python -m http.server 8000
   ```
3. Point your browser at `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

This only works for static files; it will not run your script and return the results (as Flask does).

Comment: Thanks. This is the first time that I've tried doing anything with HTML in Python so this http:server is a little over my head right now. Would this be a useful module to learn if I intend on eventually putting my code online?

Comment: @user3108789: It's really not difficult; it literally takes about 15 seconds to do. Follow the steps above and try it! To work on 'actual hosting' sites, I would use Flask instead (as above); once you have a bit of experience, try Django (but that's a much larger environment, with a bigger learning curve. Flask is much easier to get started in).