# In Python, how to open a string representing HTML in the browser?

Tags: python, django, python-webbrowser

I'd like to view a Django template in the browser. This particular template is called in [`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string), but is not connected to a view, so I can't just `runserver` and navigate to the URL at my `localhost`.

My idea was to simply call `render_to_string` in the Django shell and somehow pass the resulting string to a web browser such as Chrome to view it. However, as far as I can tell the [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/webbrowser.html) module only accepts `url` arguments and can't be used to render strings representing HTML.

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Comment: Why can't you create a view for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs):

```
import base64

html = b"..."

url = "text/html;base64," + base64.b64encode(html)
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble reproducing this snippet; it seems like [`base64.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/base64.html#base64.encode) expects two arguments, `input` and `output`. Did you mean `b64encode()`? Also the latter returns a byte string, which can't simply be 'added' to a regular string in Python 3.

Comment: Sorry, I was writing from memory and of course I've mistaken. It should be `b64encode` instead, I updated the answer

Comment: On Windows you may well get the error "ValueError: startfile: filepath too long for Windows".  See my solution below...  Also although explained, this answer still reads incorrectly.  I think the penultimate line should be: `url = "text/html;base64," + base64.b64encode(r.text.encode()).decode()`

Comment: @PeterF `html` is supposed to be a byte-like string. This answer comes from the time when Python2 was dominant and strings were bytes; I guess it's time to update the answer

Answer (score 0):

you could convert the html string to url:

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html

Answer (score 0):

Following [Launch HTML code in browser (that is generated by BeautifulSoup) straight from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437386/launch-html-code-in-browser-that-is-generated-by-beautifulsoup-straight-from-p), I wrote a test case in which I write the HTML to a temporary file and use the `file://` prefix to turn that into a `url` accepted by `webbrowser.open()`:

```
import tempfile
import webbrowser
from django.test import SimpleTestCase
from django.template.loader import render_to_string


class ViewEmailTemplate(SimpleTestCase):
    def test_view_email_template(self):
        html = render_to_string('ebay/activate_to_family.html')
        fh, path = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.html')
        url = 'file://' + path

        with open(path, 'w') as fp:
            fp.write(html)
        webbrowser.open(url)
```

(Unfortunately, I found that the page does not contain images referenced by Django's `static` tag, but that's a separate issue).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more concise solution which gets around the possible `ValueError: startfile: filepath too long for Windows` error in the solution by @marat:

```
from pathlib import Path

Path("temp.html").write_text(html, encoding='utf-8')
webbrowser.open("temp.html")
Path("temp.html").unlink()
```

Comment: If you want to store it in the filesystem, I guess [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) could simplify this a bit

Comment: Nice! Thanks for sharing that... I learned something new :)